# How do I read the schema off disk?

Tags: javascript, apollo-server

I have the following Apollo example:

```js
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server');

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`;

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  mocks: true,
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`)
});
```

I'm just not super sure what the `gql` thing is and how to pass it a string that I read from disk (my schema is too big to inline here). I tried following the definitions but it's a maze of abstraction that's hard to figure out.

Comment: I assume, it's NodeJs. You can read a file with [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options).

Comment: Yeah, but how do I put it in the `gql` thing whatever it is.

Comment: It's called [tagged template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates). It's a simple function call: `gql(file)`.

Comment: Oh, a tagged template is just a function?

Comment: No, a tagged template is a function call. A function call is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

You can read a file with [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options).

```
gql`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`
```

is a [tagged template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates). It's a simple function call: `gql(file)`.

Read the file from disk and call `gql`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server');

const file = fs.readFileSync('path', { encoding: 'UTF8' });
const typeDefs = gql(file);

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  mocks: true,
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`)
});
```